# How do I import mixins in all my css files in rails 4 asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, asset-pipeline

I am working on a Rails Application which uses SASS mixins and variables heavily. I wanted to have a mixins.css.scss file that contains all my mixins and variables then import this file into my other stylesheets in the Asset pipeline so I don't have to repeat the mixin declarations all the time. How do I import the mixins.css.scss file into all my Stylesheets? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The rails 4 docs for the Asset Pipeline ([link here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)) indicate that SASS mixins are only available in the files they're defined in. The rails 4 docs recommend using the SASS `@import` rule to import your `mixins.css.scss` file manually, checkout the relevant SASS docs [here](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import).

Depending on your need, you can import your `mixins.css.scss` into your `application.css.scss` to import into the asset pipeline (I believe you'll want it at the top of the file) or the specific SASS file for your controller/view.